# Issues with apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I can't perform an `apt-get upgrade` for some reason on kali linux. This is what happens:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apg attr couchdb cups-pk-helper docutils-common docutils-doc dwarfdump
  erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-crypto erlang-eunit erlang-inets
  erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools
  erlang-snmp erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tools erlang-webtool
  erlang-xmerl exif finger fonts-lyx freeglut3 freetds-common
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-vte-2.91
  gnome-control-center-data gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly ldap-utils libadns1
  libavcodec56 libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavformat56
  libavresample2 libavutil54 libboost-python1.58.0 libboost-python1.61.0
  libcamel-1.2-54 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcolord-gtk1
  libcrypto++9v5 libct4 libdistorm3-3 libdvbpsi9 libemu2 libexpat1-dev
  libfreerdp-rail1.1 libgeos-3.5.0 libgeos-c1v5 libglade2-0
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgrilo-0.3-0
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common libical1a
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjs-excanvas libjs-jquery-form libjs-mochikit
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libladr4 liblapack3 libldb1 libmaxminddb0
  libmozjs185-1.0 libnss-myhostname libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0
  libpango1.0-0 libpcsc-perl libpff1 libpgm-5.1-0 libphonon4 libpostproc52
  libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev libqscintilla2-12v5 libqscintilla2-l10n
  libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-script
  libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-test
  libqtassistantclient4 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2
  librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsidplay1v5 libswscale3
  libsybdb5 libtevent0 libtidy-0.99-0 libtre5 libvncclient0 libvpx1
  libvte-common libvte9 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
  libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebpdemux1 libwebpmux1 libx264-142 libzmq3
  pcsc-tools phonon phonon-backend-vlc prover9 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  python-distorm3 python-fuse python-jdcal python-matplotlib-data
  python-mpltoolkits.basemap-data python-pastedeploy-tpl python-pip-whl
  python-pyexiv2-doc python-pylibemu python3-cups python3-cupshelpers
  python3-requests python3-urllib3 reglookup-doc rwho rwhod rygel samba-common
  smitools sqsh system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev
  tdb-tools texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-base-doc u3-tool volatility-tools
  x11-apps xclip zsh zsh-common
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  vlc vlc-nox
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 35, in <module>
    import ALCLog
ImportError: No module named 'ALCLog'
Setting up apt-listchanges (3.3) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/aptlcjmM9e0.py", line 6, in <module>
    import debconf
ImportError: No module named 'debconf'
dpkg: error processing package apt-listchanges (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt-listchanges
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not sure what to do, been search for a while now and I can't seem to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason `apt-listchanges` isn't set up properly; as a result it is crashing whenever you run `apt-get`. You should remove it:

```
dpkg --remove apt-listchanges
```

This should allow `apt-get` to run again. You can always try to install `apt-listchanges` again:

```
apt-get install apt-listchanges
```